# number of ways to select the sets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Suppose there are $n$ numbers, say $1,2,3,...,n$.
We need to form $m$ sets (possibly empty) such that no two sets are the same
and the first $v$ numbers appear in an odd number of sets while the remaining $n-v$ numbers appear in an even number of sets (the remaining $n-v$ numbers may or may not be selected). In how many ways can this be done?

Comment: Without the requirement that no two sets be the same, the numbers are independent.  $1$ has to go in some odd number of sets-how many ways can it do that?  The same for $2,3,\dots v$.  Then $v+1$ has to go in an even number of sets-how many ways can it do that?  Same for $v+2, v+3 \dots n$  Multiply them all and you are done.  I don't know how to deal with the no two sets the same.

Comment: Hey ross, thanks for the prompt reply.Without the requirement that no two sets be the same the answer is pretty easy, but the challenge is when the requirement holds.

Comment: Just because there are numbers in it, it does not mean your question is about number theory. It is not about set theory, either, so I removed both tags.

Comment: Try to use inclusion-exclusion principle.Just make the right sets,then it's easy from there

Comment: Dimitris could you give me something to build upon?thanks